# Can't get count for app engine model with many to many relationship

Tags: python, html, google-app-engine, jinja2

I want to get a count of events for a single user.

My models:

```
class User(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty(required = True)
    pw_hash = db.StringProperty(required = True)
    email = db.StringProperty(required = True)

class PlaceModel(db.Model):
    place_name = db.StringProperty(required = True)
    place_lat = db.StringProperty(required = True)
    place_long = db.StringProperty(required = True)
    def render(self):
        return render_str("placemodel.html", p = self)

class EventModel(db.Model):
    event_place = db.ReferenceProperty(PlaceModel)
    event_people = db.ReferenceProperty(User)

    event_name = db.StringProperty(required = True)
    event_time = db.StringProperty(required = True)
    def render(self):
        return render_str("eventmodel.html", e = self)
```

python:

```
class MainPage(Handler): #render all userevents
    def get(self):
        email = self.session.get('foo')
        user = User.all().filter("email", email).get()
        userevents = EventModel.all().filter("event_people =", user).get()
        self.render("mainpage.html", userevents = userevents)
```

html:

```
{%if userevents.count() == 0%}
    <div>no events for now</div>
{% else %}
    {% for event in userevents %}
        {{event.event_name}}
        {{event.event_time}}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

When I run this I get an error saying the EventModel object has no attribute count. How would I get a count of the number of EventModel instances that match the user?

Comment: don't really know Jinja that well, but if it's like Django's templates, then you need to remove the `()` and just leave `userevents.count`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `.get()` on the end of the `EventModel.all()` query, you have resolved the query by getting the first value. That means that `userevents` is not a query with a `count()` method, but an actual single EventModel instance. Remove the `.get()`.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `userevents.count` to get the count of the user events.

Comment: jinja needs the (). if i remove it i get "'EventModel' object is not iterable"